# Unexpected end of JSON input at undefined line XXXX, columns xx-xx while reading in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a table in Bigquery which has 2 columns - `job_id` and `json_column`(string which is in JSON format). When I tried to read the data and identify some objects it gives me error as below:

`SyntaxError:Unexpected end of JSON input at undefined line XXXX, columns xx-xx`

It Always gives me line 5931 and second time I execute again it gives line 6215.

If it's related to JSON structure issue, how can I know which row/`job_id` that number 5931 corresponds to? If I subset for a specific `job_id`, it returns the values but when I tried to execute on the complete table, I got this error. I tried looking at the `job_id` at the row_numbers mentioned and code works fine for those `job_id`s.

Do you think its JSON structure issue and how to identify which row/`job_id` has this Issue?

Table Structure:
[image]

**Code:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
    RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
    LANGUAGE js AS """
      var result = jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
      if(result){return result;} 
      else {return [];}
    """
    OPTIONS (
        library="gs://json_temp/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
    );

SELECT job_id,dist,gm,sub_gm
FROM lz_fdp_op.fdp_json_file,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(trim(conv_column), '$.Project.OpsLocationInfo.iDistrictId')) dist ,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(trim(conv_column), '$.Project.GeoMarketInfo.Geo')) gm,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(trim(conv_column), '$.Project.GeoMarketInfo.SubGeo')) sub_gm
```

Comment: looks like issue with JSON data. you can use any online JSON Editor to locate the problem with json. Btw, why you are not using built-in JSON_EXTRACT function here. don't see in your jsonpath anything that would not be supported by built-in JSON_EXTRACT or JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - thanks, i just used the built in JSON_EXTRACT it worked for this scenario...only question is how can I read multiple arrays in an object in JSON without using unnest..i will raise a question seperately

Comment: @Nanda could you please instead of pasting picture paste a textual JSON snippet example. Without having access to the actual full file mentioning lines 5931, 6215 is completely useless, better would be to refactor you question to contain a minimal use case (provide an exact json sample and explain actual and expected output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
WITH 

T AS (
  SELECT
    '1000149.04.14' AS job_id,
    '{"Project":{"OpsLocationInfo":{"iDistrictId":"A"},"GeoMarketInfo":{"Geo":"B","SubGeo":"C"}}}' AS conv_column
)

SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(conv_column, '$.Project.OpsLocationInfo.iDistrictId') AS dist,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(conv_column, '$.Project.GeoMarketInfo.Geo') AS gm,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(conv_column, '$.Project.GeoMarketInfo.SubGeo') AS sub_gm
FROM
  T
```

BigQuery JSON Functions docs:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions

> how can I read multiple arrays in an object in JSON without using
>   unnest?

Can you explain better with an input sample your comment?

Comment: I need to read all IDs from the Combos. its present in a string field which has JSON structure .sample data below: {
  "Combos": [
    {
      "Id": "1111",
      "Type": 0,
      "Description": "ABCD",
      "ComboDuration": {
        "StartDate": "2009-10-26T08:00:00",
        "EndDate": "2009-10-29T08:00:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "Id": "2222",
      "Type": 1,
      "Description": "XYZ",
      "ComboDuration": {
        "StartDate": "2019-10-26T08:00:00",
        "EndDate": "2019-10-29T08:00:00"
      }
    }   
    
  ]
}

Comment: then probably you will have to use UNNEST to iterate over array and then extract your scalars but if you asked that in another question then guess this one is solved.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant and fpopic - Thanks for the solutions. I figured out the Issue and this was with the Incoming data where the structure wasnt complete, so we were getting these "unexpected end of Input at line xxxxx". I have fixed the Issue with the Incoming data and solution of UNNEST and the fix provided by MikahilBerlyant works good with most of the nested data I have tested so far